# Unable to decode with Swift decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, decodable

I can not figure out why this doesn't work. On the internet I found a lot of solutions with local json(not api) or with api without apiKey which in my case must be in the header(tested in Postman).

```
struct Categories: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let id: Int
    }
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        
        let api_key = "..."
        
        let urlString = "..."

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            
            request.addValue(api_key, forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    if let category = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Categories.self, from: data) {
                            print(category.name)
                        return
                    }
                }
                
                print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

I removed the `urlString` and `api_key` from the code above, but I am sure they are ok because I tested them in `Postman`

Problem - always getting printed `Fetch failed: Unknown error`

Here is how my json looks like:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "A"
            }
        },
        {
            "categories": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "B"
            }
        }....
```

Comment: `try?` => If it fails, I don't want to listen to the error, because I don't care about it. That's what it means. Use a `do/catch` and catch the error. Also, it would be good to give the output of print("Response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`, it would help seeing what your JSON looks like (and if it's really a JSON).

Comment: @Larme i have provided a part of json now, please check. thanks

Comment: I can easily see what's wrong, but I'd strongly suggest you do the try/catch, and print the error (not the localizedDescription one by the way), and read it. If you still don't understand it, you can post it here, and ask for more help. But in my opinion, learning how to debug (how to get the valuable info, even if you need help), would be much more of help for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just categories struct ... you should have these structs

```
// MARK: - Category
struct Category: Codable {
    let categories: [CategoryElement]
}

// MARK: - CategoryElement
struct CategoryElement: Codable {
    let categories: Categories
}

// MARK: - Categories
struct Categories: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}




URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            // process data
            if let category = try JSONDecoder().decode(Category.self, from: data) { print(category) }
        } catch  {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Why do I should have all those structs, you used only one of them in code?

Comment: first nothing. then I changed `Category.self` into `Categories.self` and the error is :
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: print category ... and you will get values

Comment: I have made id and name as optionals and changed `Categories.self` back again into `Category.self` as you wrote, now it works. Thanks. Can you just write here in comment why did you use 3 structs?

Comment: please upvote if it helps ... i used 3 structs because you have three levels in your json ...

Comment: first categories array , then categories dict .. and then dict itself

Comment: If you don't want redundant structs on your code, don't have redundant levels in your JSON.

Comment: ofc but its not my json :)