# Unable to parse json with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, api, alamofire

I have used Alamofire before but had no problems, looks like this time my json is a little bit weird, I can not find a way to pass it.
This is how my json looks like, I have simplified it but context is the same:

```
    {
        "categories": [
            {
                "categories": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "A"
                }
            },
            {
                "categories": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "B"
                }
            },
            {
                "categories": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "C"
                }
            }]
}
```

Also, I have a `Category` structure like this:

```
struct Category {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And finally, my `Alamofire request` :

```
func getCategories(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let baseUrl = ""
        
        let api_key = ""
        
        let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
            "user-key":api_key
        ]
        
        Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            
            guard let value = response.value as? [String:Any] else { return }
            guard let cats = value["categories"] as? [Category] else { return}
            print(cats)
            
            completed()
        }
    }
```

`Problem` - I have printed a value and it works fine, but this `print(cats)` never gets called because of the line before, it returns.
Looks like I have a problem with models and parsing, cannot figure out why.

Comment: `guard let cats = value["categories"] as? [Category] else { return}` : Reasons why `return` will be called: `value["categories"]` is nil, or `value["categories"] as? [Category]` is nil, meaning, `value["categories"]` is not a `[Category]`. Which is the case. `value["categories"]` is a `[[String: Any]]`.

Comment: Weird but yes, thats the right match. You can post this as an answer... Do you have an idea how would next match look like?

Comment: Why don't you use the suggested structs in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372221/unable-to-decode-with-swift-decodable)? With `responseData` you get the required raw data for `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: What happen with you previous answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372221/unable-to-decode-with-swift-decodable

Comment: @vadian @larme I find `Codable protocol` more complicated than this when there is very complicated(more complicated than this one) json. So i decided to move everything on Alamofire.

Comment: `Alamofire` and `Codable` are like apples and oranges. `Alamofire` is comparable to `URLSession`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire's `responseJSON(completionHandler:)` uses the [jsonObject(with:opt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject) function of the native [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization). What this does is to convert the json data to Swift native types. Whenever there is a json object like this:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "C"
}
```

will be translated to a Dictionary `[String: Any]`. Whenever there is a json array of json objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A"
    }
]
```

will be translated to an array of Dictionaries `[[String: Any]]`. So, your `getCategories(completed:)` function should, most likely, be like this:

```
func getCategories(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let baseUrl = ""
    
    let api_key = ""
    
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "user-key":api_key
    ]
    
    Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        var categories = [Category]()
        if let json = response.value as? [String: Any] {
            if let array = json["categories"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for category in array {
                    let categoryDetails = category["categories"] as? [String: Any]
                    if let id = categoryDetails?["id"] as? Int, let name = categoryDetails?["name"] as? String {
                        categories.append(Category(id: id, name: name))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print(categories)
        
        completed()
    }
}
```

This has a lot of boilerplate code. You should consider using the native [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) type and [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) instead. It needs less code.